# php debugging in eclipse

Tags: php, eclipse

How can i debug php in eclipse? Are there some plugins?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Good Free PHP debugger?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1494288/good-free-php-debugger)

Comment: -1 for not bothering to use the search option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing you'll need is a debugger extension for PHP such as Zend Debugger or XDebug.  I personally use XDebug.  Install and configure the extension.

Next you'll need PHP Developer Tools for Eclipse.  As you're already developing PHP in Eclipse I'll assume you already have the Eclipse version with PDT pre-installed or have installed it to a different version of Eclipse.

As I'm using XDebug, I'll be going over how to configure debugging with that.

Go to Window > Preferences > PHP > Debug in Eclipse and select XDebug from the dropdown for PHP debugger (you might want to specify a PHP executable as well if you want to debug PHP scripts that are intended to be run from the commandline, but that's not necessary for debugging PHP web apps).  Now you need to configure XDebug settings in Eclipse.  Next to the dropdown for PHP debugger there's a configure link.  Click that and then select Xdebug from the list that appears and click the Configure button.  You'll see several options on the page that appears.  One of these is labelled "Accept remote session".  It is very important that this value is set properly or remote debugging won't work!  Set it to localhost (if your test server is running on the same machine you're running Eclipse on), or Any or Promot if it isn't.

One last thing you'll need is an extension for Firefox called Easy XDebug.  This lets you trigger a debugging session by simply clicking an icon in the Firefox status bar.

Visit the page you want to debug, enable debugging with the Firefox extension and then reload the page.  Alt-tab back to Eclipse and you should find that the remote debugging session has started.

This article may also be helpful in the use of XDebug.

http://devzone.zend.com/article/2803-Introducing-xdebug